# Get field content of all instances of a field

Tags: 8, database

I'm trying to get the content of all instances of certain fields based on their names. I've got a list of fields (which are in nodes/paragraphs and blocks) of which I want to extract the values from.

For example `field_call_to_action_link`. I need values of all the instances of this field.

Each field has it's own database table, like: `node__field_name, paragraph__fieldname, block_content__fieldname.`

I get the field names like this ($configFieldTypes is an array of types I want):

```php
foreach ($configFieldTypes as $fieldType) {
  $fieldNamesFiltered[] = $this->entityFieldManager->getFieldMapByFieldType($fieldType);
}
```

Then I filter based on the name starting with 'field_' and make an array with the fieldname as key and the bundles associated with each field:

```php
  private function recursiveKeys($fields, &$fieldNames) {
    foreach ($fields as $key => $field) {
      if ($key === 'parent_field_name'){
        continue;
      }
      if (FALSE !== strpos($key, 'field_')) {
        $fieldNames[$key] = [$field][0]['bundles'];
      }
      if (is_array($field)) {
        $this->recursiveKeys($field, $fieldNames);
      }
    }
  }
```

The endresult is an array like this:

```php
  ["field_call_to_action_link"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["call_to_action_button"]=>
    string(21) "call_to_action_button"
  }
  ["field_image_gallery_link"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["image_gallery"]=>
    string(13) "image_gallery"
  }
```

Now I need to know if `field_call_to_action_link` is a node, block, or paragraph.

**How can I determine which database table to query?**

Drupal 8.8.x

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly you have `field_call_to_action_link` in node, paragraph, block entities. And you would like to get values from this field from all entities which contain this field.

I would use EntityQuery and condition to check if field exists in given Entity.

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
->condition('status', 1)
->condition('field_call_to_action_link', 'NULL', 'IS NOT NULL')
->execute();
```

this should give you all published nodes which contain `field_call_to_action_link`. You can obtain 'block' Entity the same way only change 'node' to 'block'.

---

**Useful links:**

- [Condition exists DOC link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Query%21Null%21Condition.php/function/Condition%3A%3Aexists/8.2.x)
- [EntityQuery DOC link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityQuery/8.2.x)

Comment: Isn't entityQuery deprecated and we should use entityTypeQuery instead?

Comment: Yes you’re right. Thanks. You should use EntityTypeManager to build query.

Comment: Ah no, for non-OOP code, `\Drupal::entityQuery()` is [not deprecated](https://www.drupal.org/node/2849874) and can still be used. For services, forms or controllers it's `$this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node')->getQuery()` or `$this->nodeStorage->getQuery()`.